# Can Excel update sheet reference (like it can with cell) when I paste content of one sheet to another?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a document where I create a new sheet which represents days (has to be that way). Each sheet has a reference to the same cell in the sheet that represents the previous day. So sheet "Tuesday" pulls some values from sheet "Monday" and so on. The formula is:

```
            Description                              Amount

="Saldo from "&TEXT($'Day03'.C4,"DD.MM.YYYY.")        =$'Day03'.F33
```

and the result I see is something like `Saldo from 1 June 2016, Amount $55.00`

If I create a new sheet and name it `Day05` and paste the content of the sheet `Day04`, is there a way to update the formula that references `Day03` to `Day04`? Right now, the content still pulls data from sheet `Day03`.

In short, when I copy the content of sheet `Day04`, I want to see the formula update to:

```
            Description                              Amount

="Saldo from "&TEXT($'Day04'.C4,"DD.MM.YYYY.")        =$'Day04'.F33
```

Right now, the sheet name reference does not update and my `Day05` sheet still pulls data from `Day03`

```
            Description                              Amount

="Saldo from "&TEXT($'Day03'.C4,"DD.MM.YYYY.")        =$'Day03'.F33 //<-- WRONG is 03 ref!
```

Comment: This is really not possible?

Comment: which version of Excel do you use? The answer depends on that

Comment: I am using Excel 2010

Comment: See [HERE](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-sheet-name-only) how to get the sheet name of the cell, then use Right or Mid to get the number and add 1 then concatenate it back together and use INDIRECT().

Comment: You are referencing cells with something like  $'Day03'.C4  but I only knew about something like  Day03!C4  . Is it your locale that makes you use dollar sign ($) and dot (.)?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is to create a new sheet, copy the content of an existing sheet, and change references to for cells to a second existing sheet. As [Satya Mishra](https://superuser.com/a/1102303) says, that could be done manually by changing `'Day03'!` to `'Day04'!` after copying to a new sheet, `Day05`.

To make the change automatically when you copy from the previous sheet to a new one, let's restate the problem: Create a new sheet and copy the content of the previous sheet. Use the name of the new sheet to make references to the previous named sheet.

Here's a formula in the current sheet that gets the contents of cell `F33` from the previous named sheet. For example, if the current sheet is `Day05`, the formula gets `F33` from sheet `Day04`.

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'Day",TEXT(MID(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",$A$1))+4,255)-1,"0#"),"'!","F33"))
```

### How the formula works

The formula uses `INDIRECT` to get a cell value from the previous sheet. If the current sheet is `Day05` and we want cell `F33`, `INDIRECT` needs a string that references cell `F33` in sheet `Day04`. The string we need is `'Day04'!F33`.

1. [Get the sheet name](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-sheet-name-only) for the current sheet.

```
Day05         =MID(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",$A$1))+1,255)
```

2. Modify the formula to get the number at the end of the sheet name by changing +1 to +4. This skips the 3 characters "Day".

```
05            =MID(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",$A$1))+4,255)
```

3. Subtract 1 to get number portion of the previous sheet.

```
4            =MID(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",$A$1))+4,255)-1
```

4. Use `TEXT` to pad the number with a leading zero.

```
04           =TEXT(MID(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",$A$1))+4,255)-1,"0#")
```

5. Use `CONCATENATE` to make the new sheet name with a reference to cell `F33`.

```
'Day04'!F33  =CONCATENATE("'Day",TEXT(MID(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",$A$1))+4,255)-1,"0#"),"'!","F33")
```

### Using the formula

Wherever you want a cell value from the previous sheet, use the formula in place of the cell reference, and change the last string in the formula to the cell reference. For example, to use cell `C4` to show the Description (notice `C4` in the formula):

```
="Saldo from "&TEXT(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'Day",TEXT(MID(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",$A$1))+4,255)-1,"0#"),"'!","C4")),"DD.MM.YYYY.")
```

The result is `Saldo from 01.06.2016.`

### Conditions and caveats

- Each sheet name must end with two numbers, e.g., `Day02`, `Day03`, etc.
- The formula won't work until the new sheet has its correct name. A wrong sheet name causes `#VALUE!` errors.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any way to have this done automatically. But a "Search and Replace" (Ctrl+H) seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution thanks to Scott Craner's comment. I warn you it's gonna be a long formula.

Everywhere you got 'DayXX' with XX number you can change te XX to

```
&MID(MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255),FIND("y";MID(CE("filename",A1),FIND("]";CEL("filename";A1))+1,255))+1,2)-1
```

This finds the filename and searches for the y from day and the extracts the nummer from the filename ands subtracts 1 from it. I can explain it more if you want, just add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Excel adapts the references to a sheet when we change this sheet's name. All the references are renamed automatically. Let's try to solve the problem with this feature: instead of renaming the references, we will **rename the sheet**.

1. Open your workbook with the sheets of the days.
2. Create the sheet with the data for the new day (say, "Day05") as you were doing previously. At the end, copy the formulas from the Day04 sheet, no matter they still refer to Day03 after the copy, and save it. Don't close the workbook yet!
3. Open another workbook, which may be empty, to hold a temporary reference, and move the Day05 sheet (to do this, right click Day05, choose 'Move or Copy...' and select the other workbook as destiny).
4. Delete sheet "Day04" and **change the name of sheet "Day03" to "Day04"**. This is the tricky part!

You can now see that the "Day05" sheet, in the new workbook, will have its references set to Day04 (from the first workbook), instead of Day03, because of the renaming. Next, let's move this sheet back to the original workbook.

5. Close the original workbook, discarding the changes made after the last save.
6. Reopen the workbook again and move back the sheet Day05 that is in the temporary workbook. The references are still to Day04 (from the current workbook), because we discarded the changes instead of renaming back the sheet.

Voilà! This is a trick to make Excel rename the references for us.

It may not seem easy to do at first glance, but I think it is easier to go with than using formulas or VBA, because you can control the steps without programming knowledge. Also, it is easier than renaming each reference.

Hope it helps!

## ***EDIT 1***

Of course, you can record a macro with this activity, and even adapt it, to be able to call it faster.